# Using fitCopula in R yields Error in optim: initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

**QUESTION:** The following **reproducable example** yields the error:

> Error in optim(start, loglikCopula, lower = lower, upper = upper,
>   method = method,  :    initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

I couldn't find out how to overcome this problem.

**To reproduce my data set:**  (simply copy paste and run the following code:)

```
#REPRODUCABLE DATA SET
###############################################
library(MASS)
library(stats)
sim.cop<- plackettCopula(param = 10) 
set.seed(1)
u<-rCopula(n = 800,copula = sim.cop)
V1<-qt(p = u[,col=1],df = 3.5)    
V1<-0.013*V1+0.0004
V2<-qt(p = u[,col=2],df = 3.5)    
V2<-0.013*V2+0.0004
m1<-fitdistr(x = V1,densfun = "normal")   
m2<-fitdistr(x = V2,densfun = "normal")   
V1.u<- pnorm(q = V1,mean = m1$estimate["mean"] ,sd = m1$estimate["sd"]) 
V2.u<- pnorm(q = V2,mean = m2$estimate["mean"] ,sd = m2$estimate["sd"])
data.u<-cbind(V1.u,V2.u)
```

**The command which yields the error**

```
#fit copula
###############################################
library(copula)
cop<-normalCopula(param = 0.5,dim = 2)     
fitting<-fitCopula(copula = cop,data = data.u,method = "ml")
```